# How should I use MVC in Ext4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I want to learn use MVC in Ext4, but the specifics in the documentation is so vague to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned MVC in ExtJS through th APP-Architecture Tutorial in the documentation

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/mvc_pt1

I took some time but then i've got it...

Comment: Also look at the source of SimpleTasks example - its full on MVC with some very good ideas.

Comment: For me in the beginning it was important to understand the MVC of ExtJS. What are the jobs of stores, views, models, controllers and how are stores and models are working togehter. My first ExtJS4-App i used the tutorial code as basement and changed it to how i needed it. And i used 
`Ext.util.Observable.capture( "OBJECT like this.store", function(e) { console.info(e);}
);` to find out which events are getting fired when i do something(click, mousemove etc.)...

Comment: I am interested in learning more about how you used the capture method.

Comment: When i started with ExtJS MVC i wasn't always sure when exactly a specific event was fired' or which events are getting fired on specific actions so you will find out what is really happening. So i put this code in the onLaunch-Method of a controller and put the name of the controll in the first parameter of ´Ext.util.Observable.capture´. 
I also used it to find out if a wrote a wrong listener when a listenercode is not executed but the event i listen to. It helps me to debug my code. The link to the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-static-method-capture

Answer (score 1):

I used the MVC Application Architecture tutorial on sencha docs, I found it a bit easier for beginners than the App Architecture series.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture